# Is there a connection between truth and good?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, middos-character-traits, emes-truth-honesty

we find that God is associated with truth and also good and that we are exhorted to pursue both,

ex. "Teach me your ways, O Lord, that I may live according to your truth" Psalm 86:11

"Turn from evil and do good" Ps.37:3

Are these two independent concepts or are they related. i.e. two sides of the same coin somehow.

Answer (score 2):

The sense of "*tov*" (good) as used in the creation story (Genesis 1) is that that which exists exists because it is good. "True" means that something *is* (exists). Therefore, they are directly related concepts. (Along these lines, the Maharal in several places defines "*tov*" as something connected to sustained existence, whereas "*ra*" (bad) is defined as something not able to continue existing.)

Comment: That is how I understood Beis Hillel's response to Beis Shammai, when they asked how can you say כלה נאה וחסודה. Beis Hillel only answered that wouldn't you want people to tell you that your purchase is good. I understood this to mean that it is not a Shekker if it helping the cause of existence.